# Matching [STRING] or [STRING]

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to match lines like these in Antlr4:

`John or apple` and `John Smith or apple sauce`.

I use the following rules:

```
conjunction : WORDS OR WORDS ;
WORDS: [A-Za-z ]+ ;
OR: ' or ' ;
```

But the first `WORDS` antlr finds also includes 'or'. So it does not see John and apple as two different words seperated by or.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Remove the space from the WORDS regex (`WORDS: [A-Za-z]+ ;`).

Comment: But I want it to be able to match spaces. See my edited post.

Comment: Does using the non-greedy operator work? (`WORDS: [A-Za-z ]+? ;`)

Answer (score 2):

In case 2 or more lexer rules match the same amount of characters, the rule define first will win. In other words, for the input `or`, bot the rules `WORDS` and `OR` can be matched. And since `WORDS` is defined first, it wins.

Swap the order:

```
conjunction : WORDS OR WORDS ;
OR: ' or ' ;
WORDS: [A-Za-z ]+ ;
```

However, ANTLR's lexer matches as much as possible. So the above will only work if you tokenize `or`. If you try to tokenize `John Smith or apple sauce`, the rule `WORDS` will match everything!

You should not include space:

```
conjunction : WORDS+ OR WORDS+ ;
OR: 'or' ;
WORDS: [A-Za-z]+ ;
SPACES: [ \t\r\n] -> skip ;
```

When I test the input `John or apple` with a parser generated from the grammar above, I get this:

[image]

and for the input `John Smith or apple sauce` this:

[image]

Comment: So the above will only work if you tokenize or. If you try to tokenize John Smith or apple sauce, the rule WORDS will match everything!

What do you mean? How can I then match what I want?
When I remove the space from `WORDS`, it doesn't work because it expends the end of the line.

Comment: @RaptorDotCpp with the first grammar I posted, if your let the lexer tokenize the input `" or "`, it will create a single `OR` token. If you let that same lexer tokenize the input `"John or apple"`, it will create a single `WORDS` token.

Comment: *How can I then match what I want?*, by doing as I suggested in my second grammar.